# Choose default cURL version

Tags: php, curl

on a CentOS 7 server the cURL version is 7.29, but there has been fixes in SMTP operation and I remember I used cURL 7.48 which works fine for me. The problem is I can't get PHP from yum to be installed against the new cURL, it always uses the old one.

The purpose for this is to install OrangeScrum system, I tried building PHP 5.4.16 from source but the system won't go to the home page, that is not a concern of this question as I am already in contact with their support.

So my question is, can I make cURL 7.48 is the default one for any package to be installed that is dependent on cURL?

Comment: Don't be put off by the version number – with RHEL/CentOS, you often get backports of bugfixes from new versions into the old one. I.e.: have you confirmed that your OrangeScrum is affected by SMTP bugs in the libcurl provided by the distro?

Comment: Well how is that done? and no I am not sure.